# Geração de amostras no R

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados com 200 observações. Gerei uma amostra sem reposição de tamanho 100 com os seguintes comandos:

```
library(car)
require(car)
(amostra1= some(dados,n=100,replace=F))
write.xlsx(amostra1,"C:/Users/../Desktop/amostra1.xlsx")
```

O meu interesse é também nas observações não-amostradas.
A pergunta é: Qual(is) comando(s) no R eu devo usar para obter as observações **não** amostradas?

Comment: `library` e `require` é redundante. Mantenha o primeiro, remova o segundo.

Answer (score 2):

Tendo em conta a forma como está a escolher a `amostra1`, a maneira natural de obter os outros dados é ou com `%in%` e `which` ou com `match`.
Primeiro vou criar um vetor `dados`.

```
library(car)

set.seed(7437)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis
dados <- rnorm(200)
```

Agora a escolha dos outros.

```
amostra1 <- some(dados, n = 100, replace = FALSE)

i1 <- which(!dados %in% amostra1)
dados[i1]

i2 <- match(amostra1, dados)
dados[-i2]

identical(dados[i1], dados[-i2])
#[1] TRUE
```

Se em vez de amostrar diretamente os `dados` amostrar *índices* do vetor `dados`, bastará negar esse índice para obter os outros.

```
j <- some(seq_along(dados), n = 100, replace = FALSE)

amostra1 <- dados[j]
outros1 <- dados[-j]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas as suas sugestões funcionam bem para dados simulados. Como ficariam as suas sugestões adaptadas para um conjunto de dados conforme segue abaixo:                 
dados <- read.xlsx("treinamento.xlsx", sheetName = "Plan1")
names(dados)

amostra1= with(dados,sample(100,replace=F))
amostra1
write.xlsx(amostra1,"C:/Users/Juliana/Desktop/amostra1.xlsx")

Comment: @Maicon Nesse caso tem um data.frame. Portanto tem de adaptar o código para um objeto com duas dimensões: `dados[j, ]` e `dados[-j, ]`. E o mesmo para os outros exemplos, com os índices `i1` e `i2`.